# Partial JSON Serialization of Object

Tags: c#-4.0

I have a collection of big object. In some scenario, I need to convert only few property of object to json string. Is there any way using `JsonConvert.SerializeObject` I can do partial object serialization? Or do I have to convert my object to another entity (smaller) and do the serialization? I am not sure `[NonSerializableAttribute]` will work there or not, but I cannot place it on other property of my object as they need to be serialized at other places